# Give new email window focus

Tags: html

I have a link on a webpage to open a new message in the default email service. The link opens and works except for the fact that the new window never has the focus. Is there a way to give it focus? I have included the link below.

`<a href='mailto:soandso@email.com?Subject=hi' target='_top' id='emailEvents'>soandso@email.com</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `target="_blank"`

```
<a href='mailto:soandso@email.com?Subject=hi' target='_blank' id='emailEvents'>soandso@email.com </a>
```

Comment: It give me the result as using target top.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I've tested using both Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 0):

```html
New Page :
<a href='mailto:test@email.com?Subject=Test' target='_blank' id='emailEvents'>test@email.com </a>

This Page :
<a href='mailto:test@email.com?Subject=Test' target='_self' id='emailEvents'>test@email.com </a>
```

Comment: Both of those give the same problem I had with target top. Thanks though.